# Python text-to-speech and speech-recognition at the same time

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, speech-recognition, text-to-speech

I am trying to create a python script that talks to itself. (example: https://vimeo.com/172440766)
I have already been able to implement text-to-speech and speech-recognition one after another, but haven't found a way to do this at the same time.

Is there a way to do these two tasks in parallel?
Appreciate any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need something done concurrently, check out the threading library: https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html

An idea would be to create a thread for your speech recognition outside of the main control flow as I imagine this will be active most of the time. For a start you could do:

```
import threading

class SpeechRecognition(threading.Thread):

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__()
        self.parent = parent

    def run(self):
        (your speech recognition function/code here)
```

and to start the speech recognition:

```
process = SpeechRecognition()
process.start()
```